# ReactiveSwift - Bind `Action` to `UIControl`

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, reactive

I am trying to bind an `Action` on a `UISwitch`.

I have created the Action using the following code

```
    action = Action<UISwitch, Bool, NoError> { (input: UISwitch) -> SignalProducer<Bool, NoError> in
        return SignalProducer{ (observer, disposable) in
            observer.send(value: input.isOn)
            observer.sendCompleted()
        }
    }
```

but I am having trouble connecting it to the `UISwitch`.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is another class `CocoaAction` that is used to wrap `Action`s and connect them to `UIControl`s (now in `ReactiveCocoa` and not in core `ReactiveSwift`, so if you are using RAC 5 you will have to import both)

```
var switch: UISwitch!

//switch.addTarget() does not retain the target, so if we do not
//keep a strong reference here the cocoaAction will be deallocated
//at the end of viewDidLoad() and you will get unrecognized selector 
//errors when the switch tries to execute the action
var switchCocoaAction: CocoaAction!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  let action = Action<UISwitch, Bool, NoError> { (input: UISwitch) -> SignalProducer<Bool, NoError> in
    return SignalProducer { (observer, disposable) in
      observer.send(value: input.isOn)
      observer.sendCompleted()
    }
  }

  //unsafe because it will cast anyObject as! UISwitch
  self.switchCocoaAction = action.unsafeCocoaAction

  switch.addTarget(switchCocoaAction,
    action: CocoaAction.selector,
    forControlEvents: .ValueChanged
  ) 
}
```

however, if all you want is a signal emitting the `switch.isOn` value whenever it changes, you can accomplish that much more easily using the builtin `rac_signalForControlEvents`

```
func switchSignal() -> SignalProducer<Bool, NoError> {
  switch.rac_signalForControlEvents(.ValueChanged) //returns legacy RACsignal
    .toSignalProducer() //legacy RACSignal -> swift SignalProducer
    .flatMapError { _ in .empty } //NSError -> NoError, errors not possible here, so ignore them
    .map { ($0 as! UISwitch).isOn }
}
```